# Get a single value where the latest date

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get the latest price of an item (as part of a larger select statement) and I can't quite figure it out.

Table:

```
ITEMID    DATE       SALEPRICE
1         1/1/2014   10
1         2/2/2014   20
2         3/3/2014   15
2         4/4/2014   13
```

I need the output of the select to be '20' when looking for item 1 and '13' when looking for item 2 as per the above example.

I am using Oracle SQL

Comment: Please user row_number, rank, dense_rank. Please check below link for more information. http://jayeshgoyani.blogspot.in/2012/11/denserank-rank-and-rownumber.html

Comment: That's why I added this thing in comments, because this will not giving exact answer, but it will helps him to resolved his issue.

Comment: @MikeW: the code will actually work on a wide range of DBMS. MySQL is more or less the only (server) DBMS that does not support window functions. The only non-standard parts are the identifiers(`#Department` is not a valid identifier in the SQL standard) and the quoting (in SQL double quotes are used for identifiers, not brackets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most readable/understandable SQL (in my opinion) would be this:

```
select salesprice from `table` t
where t.date = 
(
  select max(date) from `table` t2 where t2.itemid = t.itemid
)
and t.itemid = 1 -- change item id here;
```

assuming your table's name is `table` and you only have one price per day and item (else the where condition would match more than one row per item). Alternatively, the subselect could be written as a self-join (should not make a difference in performance).

I'm not sure about the `OVER`/`PARTITION` used by the other answers. Maybe they could be optimized to better performance depending on the DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

In `sql-server` may also work in `Oracle sql`

```
select * from
(
select *,rn=row_number()over(partition by ITEMID order by DATE desc) from table
)x
where x.rn=1
```

You need Row_number() to allocate a `number` to all records which is partition by ITEMID so each group will get a RN,then as you are ordering by `date` desc to get Latest record

## [SEE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17723)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

**Test data**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ITEMID int,DATE DATETIME,SALEPRICE INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
(1,'1/1/2014',10),
(1,'2/2/2014',20),
(2,'3/3/2014',15),
(2,'4/4/2014',13)
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ITEMID ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) AS rowNbr,
        tbl.*
    FROM
        @tbl AS tbl
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE CTE.rowNbr=1
```