# Who Is In - Get employee list latest Entry

Tags: sql

I have a table History where all of our records, IN and OUT for 2 entrance and 2 exit doors.

```
tblHistory
TimeDate    Loc IOName  LName   FName

 2014-05-07 08:20:46.000    4   Blvd Exit Male Turnstile    Abello  Allen

 2014-05-07 08:33:05.000    4   Blvd EntryTurnstile Abello  Allen

 2014-05-08 06:07:50.000    5   Main Exit Turnstile Abello  Allen

 2014-05-17 18:07:48.000    5   Main Entry Turnstile    Abello  Allen

 2014-05-18 14:26:10.000    5   Main Exit Turnstile Abello  Allen

 2014-05-18 15:48:07.000    5   Main Entry Turnstile    Abello  Allen
```

I would like to know WHO IS IN the building on the specific date/time.  I have tried below query but it ends up getting the latest activity for all the doors.  How can I make a query that will determine if the employee is IN of the premises.

```
select LName + ', ' +FName,
        IOname,
        max_date = max( TimeDate )
 from dbo.EvnLog 
 where TimeDate >= '2014-5-01' 
    and Loc in (4, 5)
 group by LName , Fname , IOname
 order by LName
```

Comment: What database are you on?  You will need to have a filter to detect if the greatest date entry is entry and not exit...I'd do it as a subquery to grab the most recent entry and join to itself to get if it was an entry or exit.  Will write it out, just need to know what databsae syntax to use

Answer (score 0):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23775358/get-a-single-value-where-the-latest-date/23775586#23775586) for a similar case.

You have to use a subselect to first select the single items (e.g. users) you want the information for and then select for each item the most recent row.

Something along these lines:

```
select  LName + ', ' + FName, IOname        
from dbo.EvnLog entries
where entries.TimeDate = (select max(TimeDate) 
                        from dbo.EvnLog t
                        where t.LName = item.LName
                        and t.FName = item.FName);
```

Answer (score 0):

take the query you provided above to get the most recent entry, turn it into a subquery (I broke lname and fname out seperately, you can do your concatonate in the select line if you want)...I'm dropping IOname at this level.

```
select a.fname + ' ' + a.lname, e.timedate as 'entry time'
from (select LName , FName,
       max_date = max( TimeDate ) as timedate
from dbo.EvnLog 
where TimeDate >= '2014-5-01' 
   and Loc in (4, 5)
 group by LName , Fname) a
inner join dbo.evnlog e on e.timedate = a.timedate and a.lname = e.lname and a.fname = e.fname
where e.ioname = 'entry'
--date filter here
```

That should work for most databases...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
FROM History h
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT
    LName,
    FName,
    MAX(TimeDate) TimeDate
FROM History
WHERE TimeDate < '2014-5-01'   --Replace '2014-5-01' with the date/time that you are searching for
GROUP BY LName, FName
) max_times
ON h.LName = max_times.LName AND h.FName = max_times.FName and h.TimeDate = max_times.TimeDate
WHERE h.IOName LIKE '%Entry%';
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph. It helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select LName + ', ' +FName, IOName, TimeDate
from dbo.EvnLog t1
where TimeDate = (SELECT MAX(TimeDate) From dbo.EvnLog t2 WHERE t1.FName = t2.FName
and t1.LName = t2.LName and TimeDate < 'YourDate')
and IOName = 'Entry'
```

The subquery gets the last row in the database before the given time.  Then we check if that row was an entry.  If it is, the user is still in the building.

Comment: Thanks Vulcronos, it also have the output that i've been looking for